# GatsbyJs client only paths goes to 404 page when the url is directly accessed in browser in "production"

Tags: gatsby

I have created a Gatsby app and configured `gatsby-node.js` to a create client only paths, which are all working fine in development while directly accessing the url of the path but not in production.

example :

```
if(page.path.match(/^\/sample/)){
     page.matchPath = "/sample/:value1/:value2/:value3";
     createPage(page)
  }
```

I am using `heroku` to deploy the app

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “client only paths” and what your specific problem is?

Comment: client only path means, the route we specify with params in gatsby-node.js file. for example when we navigate, the route would be like this:  "routeName/:param1/:param2/:param3"

Comment: Gatsby can't generate static pages that exist at paths that you don't provide. If you wanted to setup your server to route those requests to a page generated by Gatsby that uses parameters to internally route or change content you could do that, but Gatsby can't handle it solo.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion coreyward .

Comment: I have the exact same problem and am eager to understand the expected solution. Currently hosting with firebase.

Answer (score 59):

**The Why**

While the client-side router knows about this path, there is no corresponding HTML file. When the browser looks at the site it first loads the `404.html` file generated by gatsby, which includes the client-side router. Once the router completes its initialization it reads the path and loads the correct page. Meaning you end up at the right place but there's half a second of landing on the wrong page.

**How to fix It**

The general solution is to tell your server to redirect the `/sample/` path to your `/sample/index.html`file. The way to do this depends on your host, but I'll provide the name of the technique for various hosts in case you want to look it up. It's usually called URL Rewriting and should be supported by every major hosting platform.

- Netlify: [Redirects](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/)
- Firebase: [URL Rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites)
- Nginx: [Rewrite Directions](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)
- Apache: [Mod_Rewrite](https://gist.github.com/davemackintosh/8ac35fff747dbf2c95e1)
- Amazon S3: [Configuring a Webpage Redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html)
- Amazon Amplify: [Using redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html)
- Cloudflare: [URL Forwarding](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare)

**Heroku**

The Heroku section of the [gatsby deploy documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploy-gatsby/#heroku) suggests using the [heroku-buildpack-static](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#custom-routes) module which has built-in support for "custom routes" which will solve this for your case using syntax like this:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/sample/**": "sample/index.html",
  }
}
```

**AWS Amplify**

You need to add the redirect in the AWS Amplify console. For this example, the params are:

- Source URI: `/sample/<*>`
- Target URI: `/sample/index.html`
- Type: 200

Comment: this works perfectly (key is specifying index.html). This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried with firebase hosting as you've suggested. But not, working. Can you elaborate and example for firebase, please?

Comment: You can't have 200 with CloudFlare. Only 301/302 forwarding is allowed. (The new CloudFlare Pages might have a solution for this, but I still haven't received the beta access, so I'm only guessing)

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right path to fixing this problem on Vercel with rewrites. 
Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120629/77158

Comment: Works great, I had this issue again and found this answer and then realised I had liked it before, thanks again for sharing!

Comment: having this issue locally when running gatsby. is this solution supposed to work on local node server(npm run dev/start) ?

Comment: Hi, i'm using apache as webserver. My problem is that I've parameters in the url. How can I modify the configuration of Apache2 to redirect the parameters too? Otherwise the canonical url is always the same and it does not show the right parameters. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

This solves my problem

*pages/404.jsx*

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default ()=>{
  const [isMount, setMount] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
        setMount(true);
  },[])

  if(!isMount) {
     return(
        <div>loading</div>
     )
  }

  return (
     <div>Page Not Found</div>
  )


}
```

This will not show a 404 error on the client-side render until the response is 404.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who uses S3 (gatsby-plugin-s3) and CloudFront, I've resolve 302/404 by adding `generateMatchPathRewrites: false` in the gatsby-plugin-s3 config and creating a Lambd@Edge function for origin request with code below:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  if (/^\/app\//i.test(request.uri)) {
      request.uri = '/app/index.html';
  }
  return request;
};
```

Though 302/404 went away, I still have the issue when doing a hard refresh. For example when I am at /app/page2 and hit refresh, the default component in /app will load then half a second later the component in /app/page2 will show up but in a weird way. Some css classes of /app is mixed in /app/page2. If anyone has any idea about this, please let me know.

Comment: This is working for me. I am not seeing any styling issues at the moment. I now have my S3 bucket completely private! Only accessible from CloudFront and refreshes work on client only routes!

Answer (score 2):

#### Vercel

For anyone looking trying to solve this on [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) platform, the answer is rewrites: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/rewrites

If you have a gatsby app with client-only paths, as per something like https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths/, it's likely you will encounter this issue on deployment.

Example: your application has a path like **mything.com/app/user-profile**.

In this case, **app/*** are client-only routes that don't get generated on the server, so you may get a flash of a 404 when you reload this route or land on it directly from an external link, for example.

To solve, add a rewrite on the **/app/*** server side route in Vercel to point back to **/app** where, it is assumed, your routing is controlled by Reach router or similar in your **pages/app.js** file.

To set this up on Vercel, create a vercel.json in the root of your gatsby/react project and add the following configuration:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/app/:match*", "destination": "/app" }]
}
```

This issue will generally only manifest itself when deployed to production/staging. It won't occur in development (via **gatsby develop** anyway).

Answer (score 2):

For local development, you have to use the magic `[...].js` filename.

You can take a look at the demo repo here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/client-only-paths/src/pages

Comment: which gatsby version was this introduced?

Comment: This really saves my day! The name, '[...]' was easily misunderstood as a wildcard that I can rename as anything.

Answer (score 1):

I looked in the public folder to find the index file for the client route I created

for netlify I added the below to the netlify.toml file at the root.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/user/dashboard/"
  to = "/user/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Answer (score 1):

For Firebase hosting, I added the following to my `firebase.json`:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/loading/index.html"
  }
```

]

Then I created a new `loading.js` file under `/page`. With this configuration, Firebase first responds with `loading.html` then Gatsby handles the client routing.

Answer (score 1):

**NGINX**

If your environment includes Nginx you should add something like this into your virtual host config:

`rewrite ^/products/([0-9]+)$ /products/[id]/index.html;`

or

`rewrite ^/users/confirm/(.+)$ /users/confirm/[code]/index.html;`

etc.

Just go to your production root (by default this is a `/public` directory) and look for the correct path to the `index.html` file for your case. For example: `/public/products/[id]/index.html`

Usually your virtual host config is located here: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The heroku solution was not working for me, but I don't know exactly why. My frontend is fetching data from a express.js back end. I solved my problem by adding the following lines in my `server.js` to redirect my clients only routes.

```js
app.get('/user/**', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/public/user/index.html`));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Gatsby Cloud, you add this to your `gatsby-node.js`

[Working with Redirects and Rewrites](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500003051241-Working-with-Redirects-and-Rewrites)

```js
// gatsby-node.js

exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createRedirect } }) => {
 
  ...

  createRedirect({
    fromPath: '/sample/*',
    toPath: '/sample/index.html
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Gatsby React application using client-only routes ([spanishBlogTitle].js), and the dynamic routes where blinking the Home page before rendering correctly.

**FIX:**

For **AWS Amplify** this is my JSON in Rewrites and redirects:

```
[
{
    "source": "/<*>",
    "target": "/index.html",
    "status": "404-200",
    "condition": null
},
{
    "source": "/blogs/es/<*>",
    "target": "/blogs/es/[spanishBlogTitle]/index.html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
},
{
    "source": "/blogs/en/<*>",
    "target": "/blogs/en/[englishBlogTitle]/index.html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}
```

]