# Deployed Netlify page shows 404 page before displaying the actual content

Tags: gatsby, netlify

First of all, I would like to create a page that takes the URL parameter (e.g. /test/hell, which `test` is the page and `hell` is the parameter).

Therefore I created a page that takes the parameter and shows it on the title ([example](https://wizardly-banach-46e32f.netlify.com/), with the added page link at the bottom), based on the Gatsby getting started project. It seems working.

But when I open the full URL on the browser ([link](https://wizardly-banach-46e32f.netlify.com/test/hell)), it first pops up the 404 pages and then flashback to the correct content (please refresh the page to see the 404 pages). The 404 page is not what I expected so I am not sure if how to get this fixed. Also, this problem is not being observed when I run Netlify/Gatsby locally. Here is the 404 page during webpage refresh:

[image: Deployed site with refresh]

This is the [added code](https://github.com/winstonma/gatsby_test/commit/1cde1d62a04710419f4826285de238b48b9aa014) and this is the only commit that I made. I am not sure how to get rid of the 404 pages being displayed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GatsbyJs client only paths goes to 404 page when the url is directly accessed in browser in "production"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051090/gatsbyjs-client-only-paths-goes-to-404-page-when-the-url-is-directly-accessed-in)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess you are right, it has to do with the server-side redirect and the problem could be solved by installing `gatsby-plugin-netlify` plugin. The plugin will help getting the redirect done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem could be solved by setting up the `_redirects` file, required by Netlify, and the plugin [gatsby-plugin-netlify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify/) setup the `_redirects` file during build time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding a trailing slash to my link URL:
From:  **Link to="/contact"**
To:  **Link to="/contact/"**

Comment: Great! Since the plugin works and it should deal with all kinds of situation, I would stick with the plugin.

Thanks