# Dynamic path works locally but not in production

Tags: gatsby

1. Summary of the problem : 
   a. I want to dynamically generate a page in Gatsby using a path. I have implemented the technique suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55756994/6946035). This technique works locally i.e. on localhost but when I deploy it in production, I get the following error message :

> Page Not Found Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a
>   URL that doesn't exist on this site.

Expected result : After the dynamic creation of the page, @reach/router should be able to able to capture the ID in the path and make it available as props in the component.

Actual result : This works locally but in production, the browser throws the above mentioned error at me.
Error in console :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

2. What have I tried so far ?

In gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;


  if (page.path.match(/^\/resetpassword/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/resetpassword/*"

    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

In the Gatsby page resetpassword.js:

```
export default function ResetPassword() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router basepath="/">
        <ResetWorker path="/resetpassword/:id" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

function ResetWorker({ id }) {

// Here I need to access the id to make a fetch call to my node.js backend

  return()
}
```

Comment: Where are you hosting? This could be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051090/gatsbyjs-client-only-paths-goes-to-404-page-when-the-url-is-directly-accessed-in

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question ksav. The front end is hosted on Netlify and the backend is hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could useful to someone. Here is how I solved the problem based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52051090/6946035). 
1. I installed the Gatsby Netlify plugin : gatsby-plugin-netlify
2. Added `gatsby-plugin-netlify` to the plugins array of gatsby-config.js.
3. Created a _redirects file at the root of my Gatsby project with the following rule :
/resetpassword/* /resetpassword/index.html 200

The desired page is generated dynamically. Thank you ksav for your suggestion.